# Best Practices: Template Update

Tags: templates, update, bestpractice

Updating EE 2.9.2 with A COMPLETELY NEW "template". What are some best practices for implementing a completely new design (graphical site overhaul) without taking down current site or losing current entries?

IE.. Current Sections include
Home / About / Embeds / etc...
Plus my snippets and Global Variables

Should I leave the current sections and just add ...
Home16 / About16 / Embeds16 / etc...

Or is there a better way to make the graphical overhaul. Ill be adding new channels and fields for new content as well.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is a tad too broad, are you able to ask a more focused question? Is it a single template or a series of new templates, templates display content why are fearful of loosing entries etc

Comment: Question Updated.  Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 2):

You could duplicate templates and alter their names but I'd only do that if there where only a handful of items.

If you have more then is manageable by simple duplication then it warrants the creation of a dev server and work directly on the templates then transfer across to live once happy with new codebase.

You can always backup the code by using git and forking new design. As far as I know there's no best practice just what works well for you and your environment.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you will be changing quite a bit.  It may be easiest to copy all the Templates to a New Template Group.  Modify as needed in the New Template Group, test it, and then make the new Template Group the "Default" Group when you are ready to turn it on.